Angular 17 (pnpm) - Dockerfile : Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:application'
I'm having troubles trying to Dockerise my angular application using pnpm package manager. The error occurs running the command RUN ng build, I get the following error :
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:application' builder's node package.
@angular-devkit/build-angular (17.3.3) is present in my package.json. I tried to move it in the dependencies but I get the same error.
I tried to install it directly in the Dockerfile just before the ng build using RUN pnpm add @angular-devkit/build-angular but I get the following error:
0.768  ERR_PNPM_UNEXPECTED_STORE  Unexpected store location
0.768
0.768 The dependencies at "/app/node_modules" are currently linked from the store at "C:\Users\MathisDOUSSE\AppData\Local\pnpm\store\v3".
0.768
0.768 pnpm now wants to use the store at "/pnpm/store/v3" to link dependencies.
0.768
0.768 If you want to use the new store location, reinstall your dependencies with "pnpm install".
0.768
0.768 You may change the global store location by running "pnpm config set store-dir <dir> --global".
0.768 (This error may happen if the node_modules was installed with a different major version of pnpm)

Dockerfile:
FROM node:21 as base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install angular cli
RUN pnpm add -g @angular/cli

FROM base AS prod-deps
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

FROM base AS build
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm add @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN ng build

FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Has anyone faced the same issue and knows how I could resolve it ? Thank you !
